# How to calculate mouse position relative to drawing area when it hovers over element being drawn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

Imagine simple ms paint application written in react and you are trying to implement rectangle drawing.

It's something I currently have but if I drag my mouse over rectangle I am currently drawing it starts to flicker because it fires event with position relative to rectangle and not drawing area (in my case `div`) depending over which element (drawing area/rectangle) my mouse is currently over.

I have extracted the problem into this simple app https://codesandbox.io/s/6yxx4y9lz3

I feel like I could solve the problem with hacky calculations but I would appreciate some elegant solution/advice as this functionality is going to be base stone of bigger application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that the blue box you are drawing eats up the mouse events.

You can just add `pointer-events:none` to it so that it is ignored. (*`pointerEvents` when used from inside React*)

```
style={{
    width: item.w,
    height: item.h,
    top: item.y,
    left: item.x,
    border: "solid blue",
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents:"none"
}}
```

Updated demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/l7ll3wy5pl

Comment: That was exactly it! I didn't even know something like `pointerEvents` exist thank you.